# Gaussian Elimination with Parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

Can someone please help me with the solution of
\begin{align}(\lambda+1)x+y&=\lambda+1\\
x+(\lambda+1)y&=1\\
x+y&=2\lambda+1\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

from the first equation we get
$$y=\lambda+1-(\lambda+1)x$$
plugging this in the second equation we have
$$x(-\lambda^2-2\lambda)=-\lambda^2-2\lambda$$
if $$-\lambda^2-2\lambda=0$$
we get $$\lambda=0$$ of $$\lambda=-2$$
in the first case we get infinity many Solutions.
for the other case we get no Solutions.
If $$\lambda\ne 0$$ or $$\lambda\ne -2$$
from here we get $$x=1,y=0$$ plugging this in the last equation we get
$$1=\lambda+1$$ thus it must be $$\lambda=0$$ in the other case there are no Solutions.

Comment: $x=y=1$ cannot be a solution.

Comment: you must read my whole post

Comment: ok i have corrected it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the third from the second,

$$\lambda y=-2\lambda.$$

This is possible if either

- $\lambda=0$, then all three equations reduce to $x+y=1$;
- $y=-2$, giving

$$\begin{cases}(\lambda+1)x=\lambda+3,\\x=2\lambda+3\end{cases}$$ which requires

$$(\lambda+1)(2\lambda+3)=\lambda+3.$$

To summarize

$$\lambda=0\to (t,1-t),$$
$$\lambda=-2\to (-1,-2).$$

---

More systematic:

The system has a solution when the determinant

$$\begin{vmatrix}\lambda+1&1&\lambda+1\\1&\lambda+1&1\\1&1&2\lambda+1\end{vmatrix}=2l^3+4l^2$$ vanishes.

Then

- $\lambda=0\to$

$$\begin{cases}x+y&=1\\
x+y&=1\\
x+y&=1,\end{cases}$$

giving $y=1-x$,

- $\lambda=-2\to$

$$\begin{cases}-x+y&=-1\\
x-y&=1\\
x+y&=-3\end{cases},$$

giving $x=-1,y=-2$.

Comment: The condition $\det(a_1, a_2, b) = 0$ seems correct to enforce $0 = z = \det(a_1,a_2,b) / \det(a_1, a_2, a_3)$ in an extended system $(a_1, a_2, a_3) (x,y,z)^T = b$, using Cramer's rule, keeping the same solution set as $(a_1, a_2) (x,y)^T=b$, for some linear independent $a_3$.  I wonder if there is an easier justification.

Comment: @mvw: make the system homogeneous. It has a nontrivial solution only when the determinant is zero.

Answer (score 0):

If we sum the first and the second we get
$$(\lambda+2)x+(\lambda+2)y=\lambda+2$$
If $\lambda\neq -2$ we can divide by $\lambda+2$ to get
$$x+y=1$$
We also have
$$x+y=2\lambda+1$$
So $\lambda=0$ and the system has infinitely many solutions which you can parametrize.
If $\lambda=-2$ we get $-x+y=-1$ and $x+y=-3$ adding them together we get $y=-2$ and $x=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can write that system more compact as
$$
A u = b \iff \\
[A | b] =
\left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
\lambda + 1 & 1 & \lambda + 1 \\
1 & \lambda + 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2\lambda + 1
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & 1 & 2\lambda + 1 \\
\lambda & 0 & -\lambda \\
0 & \lambda & -2 \lambda
\end{array}
\right]
$$
At this point we need to distinguish further between $\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda \ne 0$.

**Case $\lambda = 0$:**
We proceed with the system
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
$$
which has the line $L = \{ (x, y) \mid x + y = 1 \}$ as solution.

**Case $\lambda \ne 0$:**
We continue with the system
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & 1 & 2\lambda + 1 \\
\lambda & 0 & -\lambda \\
0 & \lambda & -2 \lambda
\end{array}
\right]
$$
We are allowed to divide by $\lambda$ and get
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & 1 & 2\lambda + 1 \\
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & -2
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & -2 \\
1 & 1 & 2\lambda + 1
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 2\lambda + 4
\end{array}
\right]
$$
The equation of the last row can only be solved if $2\lambda + 4 = 0 \iff \lambda = -2$ leading to the solution $(x,y) = (-1,-2)$.

**Summary**

We found a single solution $(-1,-2)$ if $\lambda = -2$, a line of solutions $L = \{ (x,y) \mid x + y = 1 \}$ for $\lambda = 0$, for other values of $\lambda$ the system has no solutions.

Comment: There is no reason to consider the case $\lambda=-1$ specifically.

Comment: Thanks. I found it interesting, but it is not required. I shortened it.